# Move to Graphics Design instead of close?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Recently, [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/perception-and-color-theory) was closed on UX. I think that that is a pity, even though it does not belong on UX. The question IMHO shows real effort. Would this question be welcome on Graphics Design instead perhaps? Could it be moved there instead of just closed? Or is it welcome here?

Comment: +1 good idea...

Comment: Agreed, moving questions should be considered before closing them.

Comment: I'm glad somebody with enough powers agreed, as it seems the message has indeed been moved over. Thanks!

Comment: Send 'em over...we'd love to have them!